# How to turn a list of dictionaries of lists into a list of lists of dictionaries for each combination

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to define python function which takes a list of dictionaries in which some keys could be lists and then returns a list of list of dictionaries in which each key is a single value, which corresponds to all the combinations of options (an option is picking a single value from each list).

Consider the following input:

```
input = [
         {
          "name": "A",
          "option1": [1, 2],
          "option2": ["a1", "a2"]
         }
         {
          "name": "B",
          "option1": [3, 4],
          "option2": "b1"
         }
        ]
```

Given this input, the desired output would be:

```
output = [[{"name": "A", "option1": 1, "option2": "a1"}{"name": "B", "option1": 3, "option2": "b1"}]
          [{"name": "A", "option1": 1, "option2": "a1"}{"name": "B", "option1": 4, "option2": "b1"}]
          [{"name": "A", "option1": 1, "option2": "a2"}{"name": "B", "option1": 3, "option2": "b1"}]
          [{"name": "A", "option1": 1, "option2": "a2"}{"name": "B", "option1": 4, "option2": "b1"}]
          [{"name": "A", "option1": 2, "option2": "a1"}{"name": "B", "option1": 3, "option2": "b1"}]
          [{"name": "A", "option1": 2, "option2": "a1"}{"name": "B", "option1": 4, "option2": "b1"}]
          [{"name": "A", "option1": 2, "option2": "a2"}{"name": "B", "option1": 3, "option2": "b1"}]
          [{"name": "A", "option1": 2, "option2": "a2"}{"name": "B", "option1": 4, "option2": "b1"}]]
```

Comment: there are duplicate entries in the output, is it intended?

Comment: What was your attempt that failed?

Comment: I have just realised a mistake that I have made. The output is supposed to be a list of lists of dictionaries, rather than a list of dictionaries. The post and the title have been edited.

Comment: `list(map(list, product(*[[reduce(lambda x, y: x.update(y) or x, d) for d in product(*map(lambda x: list(x[1]), groupby(i, key=lambda x: x.keys())))] for i in [[{k: val} for k, v in d.items() for val in (v if type(v) is list else [v])] for d in arr]])))` if you like this one line. ; )

Answer (score 0):

Let's try something like this.

```
import itertools 


input = [
     {
      "name": "A",
      "option1": [1, 2],
      "option2": ["a1", "a2"]
     },
     {
      "name": "B",
      "option1": [3, 4],
      "option2": "b1"
     }
    ]

list_opts = [y 
         for x in input 
         for y in [x['option1'] 
                   if type(x['option1']) == list 
                   else [x['option1']], 
                   x['option2'] 
                   if type(x['option2']) == list 
                   else [x['option2']]]]
list_combinations = list(itertools.product(*list_opts))
output = [[{"name": "A", 
        "option1": x[0], 
        "option2": x[1]}, 
       {"name": "B", 
        "option1": x[2], 
        "option2": x[3]}] 
      for x in list_combinations]
```

Here's what I got.

```
[[{'name': 'A', 'option1': 1, 'option2': 'a1'},
  {'name': 'B', 'option1': 3, 'option2': 'b1'}],
 [{'name': 'A', 'option1': 1, 'option2': 'a1'},
  {'name': 'B', 'option1': 4, 'option2': 'b1'}],
 [{'name': 'A', 'option1': 1, 'option2': 'a2'},
  {'name': 'B', 'option1': 3, 'option2': 'b1'}],
 [{'name': 'A', 'option1': 1, 'option2': 'a2'},
  {'name': 'B', 'option1': 4, 'option2': 'b1'}],
 [{'name': 'A', 'option1': 2, 'option2': 'a1'},
  {'name': 'B', 'option1': 3, 'option2': 'b1'}],
 [{'name': 'A', 'option1': 2, 'option2': 'a1'},
  {'name': 'B', 'option1': 4, 'option2': 'b1'}],
 [{'name': 'A', 'option1': 2, 'option2': 'a2'},
  {'name': 'B', 'option1': 3, 'option2': 'b1'}],
 [{'name': 'A', 'option1': 2, 'option2': 'a2'},
  {'name': 'B', 'option1': 4, 'option2': 'b1'}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

While George's answer might produce correct output, it could be problematic in case of exending the solution to more options.

Here's what I came up with:

```
import copy
import itertools

input = [
         {
          "name": "A",
          "option1": [1, 2],
          "option2": ["a1", "a2"]
         },
         {
          "name": "B",
          "option1": [3, 4],
          "option2": "b1"
         }
        ]

def dictContainsListVals(dic):
    return any([isinstance(val, list) for val in dic.values()])

def splitDict(dic):
    flattenedDicts = [dic]
    while any(dictContainsListVals(dic) for dic in flattenedDicts):
        splitDict = flattenedDicts.pop(0)
        for key, value in splitDict.items():
            if isinstance(value, list):
                for el in value:
                    dictCopy = copy.deepcopy(splitDict)
                    dictCopy[key] = el
                    flattenedDicts.append(dictCopy)
                break
        else:
            flattenedDicts.append(splitDict)
    return flattenedDicts

flattenedDicts = []
for dic in input:
    flattenedDicts.append(splitDict(dic))
output = itertools.product(*flattenedDicts)
print(list(output))
```

Output:

```
[({'name': 'A', 'option1': 1, 'option2': 'a1'}, {'name': 'B', 'option1': 3, 'option2': 'b1'}), 
({'name': 'A', 'option1': 1, 'option2': 'a1'}, {'name': 'B', 'option1': 4, 'option2': 'b1'}), 
({'name': 'A', 'option1': 1, 'option2': 'a2'}, {'name': 'B', 'option1': 3, 'option2': 'b1'}), 
({'name': 'A', 'option1': 1, 'option2': 'a2'}, {'name': 'B', 'option1': 4, 'option2': 'b1'}), 
({'name': 'A', 'option1': 2, 'option2': 'a1'}, {'name': 'B', 'option1': 3, 'option2': 'b1'}), 
({'name': 'A', 'option1': 2, 'option2': 'a1'}, {'name': 'B', 'option1': 4, 'option2': 'b1'}), 
({'name': 'A', 'option1': 2, 'option2': 'a2'}, {'name': 'B', 'option1': 3, 'option2': 'b1'}), 
({'name': 'A', 'option1': 2, 'option2': 'a2'}, {'name': 'B', 'option1': 4, 'option2': 'b1'})]
```